# How can I apply a Web Part to all the sub sites?

Tags: web-part, 2013, publishing-site, page-layout

I have an Enterprise Wiki site collection and it have 5 sub sites, currently I have implemented a Web Part which extended the page layout.
But I am facing this:-

1. To apply the page layout I have to add the web part 6 times ( 1 for the main site and 5 times for each sub site). 
   So my question is if I can apply the Web Part once to the main site and have the effect on all the sub sites.

[image]

Comment: You could "Save as template" on a site which has the extending webpart on it and use that template to create new subsites which would automatically have it inserted upon creation. This is only possible if your site is not a Publishing site.

Comment: my site is a publishing site and all th site are based on the Enterprise Wiki template.

Comment: Another option would be to develop a site template which has the webpart on its default.aspx page. Is that an option for you?

Comment: well i did not develop a site template before,, may i need to check how to do it before, and for now i can live with the fact that i have to add the web part for each subsite separately..?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new page layout based on the Enterprise wiki but including your web part. This page layout can then be used by all your Enterprise wiki sub-sites.  The simplest way is probably to copy the existing Enterprise wiki page layout in the first instance.  You will need to use something like SharePoint Designer to achieve this.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more on this, do some research on the Design Manager. One of the greatest benefits to page layouts in 2013 is the ability to add Snippets, which include web parts. Simply include the web part in the page layout and then assign the page layout to each page you want to have that new page layout.

Comment: i navigate to the "Design Manager---> Edit Page Layouts". But the enterprisewiki.aspx page was not listed there ?